# I am trying to disable my own mic in kurento many-to-many tutorial but no success till now

Tags: audio, webrtc, kurento

I have tried this code

participant.audioEnabled=false

but nothing happens .I want to disable just mic not my speaker any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

`audioEnabled` properties there.

```
 participants[name].rtcPeer.audioEnabled = false;
```

or

```
participants[name].rtcPeer.peerConnection.getLocalStreams()[0].getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
```